# Programatically get a list of all workspaces (shared+Personal) in VisualForce Page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have created a custom visualforce page.
Here in the controller class i want to get a list of all workspaces in a dropdown so that user can make a choice among where to publish the data

Can somebody provide me some guidelines on how to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated.
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to query the content workspaces and then put them in select option list which can then be referenced in a visualforce page.

Apex Controller:

```
public Id selectedWorkspaceId { get; set; }

private List<SelectOption> workspaceOptions;
public List<SelectOption> getWorkspaceOptions() {
 if(workspaceOptions == null) {
  for(ContentWorkSpace workspace : [select id, name from ContentWorkspace]) {
   workspaceOptions.addNewSelectOption(
    new SelectOption(workspace.id, workspace.name);
   }
  }
 }
 return workspaceOptions;
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedWorkspaceId}" size="1">
 <apex:selectOptions value="{!workspaceOptions}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Documentation:

- [`SelectOption` Class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_pages_selectoption.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_pages_selectoption.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)
- [`<apex:selectList>` component](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_compref_selectList.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/pages_compref_selectList.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)
- [`<apex:selectOptions>` Component](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_compref_selectOptions.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/pages_compref_selectOptions.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)
- [`ContentWorkSpace` object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_objects_contentworkspace.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspace.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

Comment: Ralph i got this to work but i couldnt get the value of selected Workspace in the property named = selectedWorkspaceId in my controller class it always shows null.Any suggestion how can i get this..

Comment: Ralph with this i can get all shared workspace but what about personal workspace.cant get any info about it

Comment: The docs (see link for ContentWorkspace docs in answer) seem to imply it's not possible to query personal workspaces.  "This object does not apply to personal libraries."  You may want to log a case with support to see if they have an other insight.  To get only the shared workspaces that are visible to the running user I believe you can use the "with sharing" keyword in your class definition (not tested).

Comment: I don't think that personal Workspaces are represented directly by the ContentWorkspace object in the object model. The ContentWorkspace object is only for public workspaces. Documents in personal workspaces can be retrieved by retrieving the ContentDocument objects for a given user with a PublishStatus of "R".

Answer (score 0):

Below is Java code (from code reciepe) to Query a List of Workspaces in Salesforce CRM Content. Translate below code to apex and it should work.

```
package com.sforce;

import org.apache.axis.client.Stub;

import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.*;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.*;

public class QueryWorkspace {

    /**
     * @param args
     */  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QueryWorkspace queryWorkspace = new QueryWorkspace();
        try {
            queryWorkspace.queryAvailableWorkspaces();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    private void queryAvailableWorkspaces() throws Exception {

        SforceServiceLocator sforceServiceLocator
            = new SforceServiceLocator();

        SoapBindingStub binding
            = (SoapBindingStub) sforceServiceLocator.getSoap();

        // Login  

        LoginResult lr = binding.login("user@jstest.org",
                "password");

        binding._setProperty(Stub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                lr.getServerUrl());

        // Create a session header for subsequent calls  

        _SessionHeader sessionHeader = new _SessionHeader();
        sessionHeader.setSessionId(lr.getSessionId());
        binding.setHeader(sforceServiceLocator.getServiceName()
                .getNamespaceURI(), "SessionHeader", 
        sessionHeader);

        QueryResult query
            = binding.query("select Id, Name from" 
            + " ContentWorkspace");

        SObject[] records = query.getRecords();
        if (records != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                ContentWorkspace contentWorkspace =
                    (ContentWorkspace)records[i];
                System.out.println("Workspace Id:"
                        + contentWorkspace.getId() + " Name:"
                        + contentWorkspace.getName());
            }
        }        
    }

}
```

Comment: i saw this and tried to transform it as per my requirement but couldn't be done.hope somebody has done this in APEX.

Comment: Can you pls share Apex Code that you tried, might be you are missing something really small ..

Comment: ignore above comment (i just noticed answer comment)